# Replacing MOTD with a Gif

Tags: linux, rhel

I am hoping to add a gif as my computers motd. Right now I have the motd printed using zenity. I don't think that it allows for gifs. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You might have to settle for Ascii Art.

```
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
 MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM  MM''MMMMM
 MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM  M'  MMMMM
 MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM!" ''' "!MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM  M  MM"'MM
 MMMMMM'"M' MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMV'                '"MMMMMMMMMM.  'MM  M  M' .MM
 MMMM'M :M ;MV MMMMMMMMMM'                      "MMMMMMMMMM.  ": M .! .MMM
 MMM; M  M :M' AMMMMMMV'                          "MMMMMMMMM.  .'''. AMMMM
 MMMM ;  ; M:  MMMMMM'                              'MMMMMMM'        MMMMM
 MMMM. ; . M  AMMMMV                                 'MMMM"" ' '.   .MMMMM
 MMMMM  .    MMMMMV                                    '. ..    ;  .MMMMMM
 MMMM  '"@"  MMMMV                                      MMMMMM.'   MMMMMMM
 MMMM.  ;        '                                      'MMMMMM.   MMMMMMM
 MMMMM..'.   .MM'                                        MMMMMMM    VMMMMM
 MMMMMM  AMMMMMV                                         'MMMMMM.    MMMMM
 MMMMM'  MMMMMM:                                     ..   MMMMMMM     MMMM
 MMMMM   MMMMMM: @@.                              .'  @@  : 'MMMM.     MMM
 MMMM'   MMM''': :@: '.                         .' ..@@@  :            .MM
 MMMV   ''     : '@@@@: '.                    .'  .@@@@@  ........./MMMMMM
 MMM           :  @@@@@. .' .              .' A. .@@@@@'  MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
 MMM:..........:  '@@@@@@@.  ! '. - - - . '.  .@@@@@@@@   MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
 MMMMMMMMMMMMMMM   '@@@@@@@@@@@@.    !    .@@@@@@@@@@@@'  MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
 MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM   '@@@@@@@@@@@@@...@@'..@@@@@@@@@@@@'  AMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
 MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMA   '@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@   .MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
 MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMA    @@@@@@@@@@@@"'O'OOOO'@@@@@@@'   .MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
 MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMA    '@@@@@@@VOOOOOOO.OOO @@@V     AMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
 MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMA     '@@@@OOOOOOOOO.OOO@'     .MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
 MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMA        '.@@.OOOOO.OO     .AMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
 MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMA.          OOOOO OOOO .MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
 MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMA..      OOOOOOOOOOOMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
 MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMOOOOOOOOOO.MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
 MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM OOOOOOO.MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
 MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM---MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
 MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
```